# UK Visa application money

Tags: visas, uk, money

I'm applying for an UK visa, and there is a question, I don't know what to write:

**What is the total amount of money you spend each month?** *Include living costs, money given to dependants, rent or mortgage, and any other bills or costs.*

I'm a student (16 year old), and I don't spend money on rent and stuff.Should I write my parents's spending amount? If I write 400 GBP is that okay?

**Do you have another income or any savings?**
I should write no, right? I'm not working, and my school is also free.

Comment: If you have no savings, answer ‘no’. If you have savings, answer ‘yes’. Reading this question may be helpful https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Comment: but like if I have 100GBP on my credit card (from my mom), does that counts as savings?